# AWS MSK Connector State Transition Logic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

AWS MSK Connector has these 5 states,

1. CREATING
2. RUNNING
3. FAILED
4. UPDATING
5. DELETING

I cannot find how MSK Connect knows when to transition from CREATING to RUNNING or FAILED state.

CREATING -> FAILED:= Mostly can be figured out, after hearing on logs saying "Kafka Connect stopped"

how does it figure out the Transition to the RUNNING state?
When a Kafka Connect Process runs it logs "Kafka Connect Started", it can say that the connect got started, but from the AWS console, it seems it doesn't transition to running start at that point in time, which also seems fine as there may be issue bcoz of connector-properties .
so, when MSK Connect knows to transition?

Comment: Removed MSK flags since state transitions are open-source Connect API behavior... I suspect MSK polls the Connect REST API /status endpoint, but this could be delayed in any UI view

Comment: The status update is very much delayed, a State Transition from Creating -> Running/Failed takes anywhere between 5-10 mins, not only UI, but their status check via API, also reflects a delayed transition, I don't know how they are doing it. The /status endpoint should not be that delayed. Anyways Thanks

Comment: You'll need to contact their support to find the answers you want since it's a closed system